# the method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, class, methods, arguments

I get this error:

> the method pintar() in the type t33.Psicodelia is not applicable for the arguments (int,int,int,int,int,int)

How can I solve this?

I have two classes and the main tab:

Class 1

```
public class Logica {
  Psicodelia miPsicodelia;


  public Logica() {
  }

  public void pintar() {
    miPsicodelia.pintar(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);
    miPsicodelia.kaleidouno(posX, posY, rad, ang, depth, tam1);
  }  

  public void pressed() {
    miPsicodelia.pressed();
  }
}
```

Class 2

```
public class Psicodelia {
  private float anguloGrande;
  private int numBolas, contador;


  public Psicodelia() {
    stroke(255);   
    this.anguloGrande = 0.0;
    this.numBolas = 7;
  }


  public void pintar() {
    //fill((int)random(0, 255), (int)random(0, 255), (int)random(0, 255));
    fill(255, 255, 0, (int)random(20, 100));
    pintar(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);
    anguloGrande += .02; //velocidad de rotacion
  }

  public void kaleidouno(float posX, float posY, float rad, float ang, int depth, float tam) { //pinteme las bolas en la pos posX, posY, reciba un float de radianes y de angulos, y por ultimo un int de profundidad
    if (depth < contador) {
      tam=(int)random(0.5, 1.5);
      float anguloPeq = TWO_PI/numBolas;
      for (int i=0; i < numBolas; i++) {
        float nuevoRad = rad/2; //distancia y tamaño de las bolas entre ellas
        float nuevoAng = ang + i*anguloPeq - anguloGrande;
        float X = cos(nuevoAng)*rad + posX;
        float Y = sin(nuevoAng)*rad + posY;
        pintar(X, Y, nuevoRad, nuevoAng, depth + 1, 1);
      }
    }
    else  if (rad < 2) { 
      ellipse(posX, posY, 2.0*tam, 2.0*tam);
    }
    else { 

      ellipse(posX, posY, rad*2.0, rad*2.0);
    }
  }

  public void pressed() {
    contador++;
    if (contador >= 3) { 

      contador--;
    }
  }



  float getPosX () {
    return posX ;
  }


  float getPosY () {
    return posY ;
  }
}


// and the main tab


Logica miLogica;

//================================================================

void setup() {
  size(800,600);
  smooth();

miLogica= new Logica();

}

//================================================================

void draw() {
  background(0);
 miLogica.pintar();

}

//================================================================

void mousePressed() {
miLogica.pressed();
}
//================================================================
```

Comment: It looks like in class `Psicodelia` in the method `pintar()` that you are calling `pintar(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);` when you should actually be calling `kaleidouno(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);`.

Comment: where is the function definition for pintar(int,int,.,.,.,.,.,.)?? You are having the mathod as pintar() without argument  in the class 2;

Answer (score 3):

You called the method

```
Psicodelia miPsicodelia;
miPsicodelia.pintar(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);
```

But your `Psicodelia` class only has following `pintar` method:

```
public void pintar();
```

To call it the way you did you must give the method `pintar()` the wished parameter.

For Example:

```
public void pintar(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f){
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

*P.S.: Do you instantiate your* `miPsicodelia` *Object anywhere? If not this will get you a* `NullPointerException`*.*

Comment: thanks, i tried that but if i do that, i get unexpected token:int

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Have you implemented the `public void pintar(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)` Method in your `Psicodelia` class? Where exactly does the error show up? A Line number would help.

Comment: i wrote this line.     miPsicodelia.pintar(int width/2, int height/2, int height/4, int 0, int 0, int 1);

Comment: Okay, no, not that way. When you write `miPsicodelia.pintar(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);` you mean, that you go into the class of `miPsicodelia` (that is `Psicodelia`) and look for the method 'pintar' with the parameter 'int,int,int,int,int,int', that means, you need a method `public void pintar(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f){...}` method in your `Psicodelia` class. Because there is at them moment just `public void pintar(){...}` you have do declare a new method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless I miss something, your `public void pintar()` method is declared with no parameters, so you can't call it with any. You'd have to declare it with your desired number and types of parameters:

```
public void pintar(int para1, int para2, int para3, int para4, int para5, int para6)
{ 
   //Do something with the parameters.
}
```

Comment: i know but i said above that if give it parameters i get unexpected token:int

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The _declaration_ is wrong. You create the method as `public void pintar() { //... }` without any parameters. So when you try to call `miPsicodelia.pintar(width/2, height/2, height/4, 0, 0, 1);`, your method doesn't know what to do with the numbers it gets.